# Best experience for copying tabs from multiple document types?

Tags: tabs

Requirement: User can create a new online specification from multiple previous specifications

Each specification is made up of multiple online tabs.

The only way I can see to do this is to do something like Microsoft Word Clipboard where each of the tabs can be copied. See attached!

Is this the easy enough? the users are not very tech savvy..

[image]

Comment: I don't understand. First the title of the page is Document 1, then by switching tabs (which are visually subordinate to the title) to Tab 2 the page title switch. And how do you trigger that "contextual menu", by right clicking? And what has happened between image 1 and image 2?

Comment: I don't think there is enough detail here, in both what you are trying to do and how the illustrated interface would work.

Answer (score 1):

Since your users are "not very tech savvy" I would suggest not to use the clipboard.

Clipboard actions are usually not visible to the user since they are done via keyboard shortuts. These actions are used by powerusers but from your explanation I can conclude that your user do not fall into that category.

You need actions that are visible and 'discoverable' by the user and you'll probably want to guide them, or they will probably never use it.

Here are two ideas that come to mind:

- A 'Create new spec' option in the toolbar which opens a tool in which they can create a new specification using the information from other specs. This is quite an extensive solution though.
- Show the list of specs on the left and let the users drag and drop items from the currently opened specs into other specs. Similar to creating a playlist in spotify or itunes. You have a list of playlists on the left and you either drag new songs into the list, or select a song and use the toolbar or contextmenu to say: 'Add this song to *'My awesome list of songs'*';